# Sum Like Child Variables

Tags: javascript

How would I sum the qty variable in each parent variable without doing (flower.blueyellow.qty + flower.redyellow.qty) in the following code:

```
var flower = {
 blueyellow: { 
    color : "linear-gradient(to right, blue, yellow)",
    src : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/07/22/15/11/woman-7338352_1280.jpg",
    price : 30,
    qty : 0,
    size : "small"
  },
 redyellow: { 
    color : "red, yellow",
    src : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/05/22/16/50/outdoors-7213961_1280.jpg",
    price : 25,
    qty : 0,
    size : "large"
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far? also, you can't sum a variable if you can't access it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the property values of the object with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the array and sum the `qty` property:

```js
const flower={blueyellow:{color:"linear-gradient(to right, blue, yellow)",src:"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/07/22/15/11/woman-7338352_1280.jpg",price:30,qty:0,size:"small"},redyellow:{color:"red, yellow",src:"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/05/22/16/50/outdoors-7213961_1280.jpg",price:25,qty:10,size:"large"}};

const sum = Object.values(flower).reduce((a, {qty}) => a += qty, 0)
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var flower = {
 blueyellow: { 
    color : "linear-gradient(to right, blue, yellow)",
    src : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/07/22/15/11/woman-7338352_1280.jpg",
    price : 30,
    qty : 0,
    size : "small"
  },
 redyellow: { 
    color : "red, yellow",
    src : "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/05/22/16/50/outdoors-7213961_1280.jpg",
    price : 25,
    qty : 0,
    size : "large"
  }
};

const sum = Object.values(flower).reduce((acc,current) => {
    return acc + current.qty
},0)

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let sum = 0
for (let [key,value] of Object.entries(flower)) {
  sum += value.qty
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.